# Can't access dockerized MongoDB (with mongo express) using pymongo - gets directed to another db

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, pymongo

I'm trying to run a db with a python app that interacts with it. I have the db running using this `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    flask_app:
        build: ./flask_app
        container_name: flask_app
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
    mongo:
        image: mongo:latest
        container_name: mongodb
        environment:
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
        volumes:
            - /data/db:/data/db
    mongo-express:
        image: mongo-express:latest
        container_name: mongo_express
        environment:
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongo
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT=27017
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN=true
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_AUTH_DATABASE=admin
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=root
            - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=pass
            # Uncomment if a secure login via browser is required
            # - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME=root
            # - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD=pass
        links:
            - mongo
        ports:
            - 8081:8081
```

I can access the DB at *localhost:8081*: [image]

And I hopes to access the same db, using `pymongo`, given that the **/data/db** volume is mapped from the host to the container.

However, as shown below, I access another DB (one with "todos", "test_db" and "db" but without "config") [This python runs on the host, not in the app container, if this changes something]:

```
In [1]: from pymongo import MongoClient; client = MongoClient(host='localhost', port=27017)

In [2]: client.list_database_names()
Out[2]: ['admin', 'local', 'db', 'todos', 'test_db']
```

What am I missing here? Why there are 2 DBs?

Comment: You did not forward the port `27017` of container `mongodb` to the host.

Comment: I am no expert in mongo, but as far as I understand it, mongo-express is a frontend for mongo. The container `mongo_express` can access `mongodb` since they are on the same (virtual) network. You can connect to the container directly from the host machine through the ip of the container. Or you can use a port-forward from the container to the host machine (by a `ports` section in `docker-compose.yml`).

Comment: The error message means that there is already a process running that uses port `27017`. You may want to stop this application or remap to a different local port (e.g. `28017`)

Comment: Yes, I forgot I spawned an older mongo here. Killed it and now its working. The port mapping did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We did not forward the port `27017` of container `mongodb` to `localhost`, thus there is no application running on `localhost:27017`.

We can either access the container directly through its IP address from the host, or we can create a port forward form the docker host to the container, such that we can access the mongo database through `localhost:27017`.

To do the latter, we modify add a `ports` section to container `mongodb` in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    ...
    mongo:
        image: mongo:latest
        container_name: mongodb
        ...
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
    ...
```